# Understanding the free $R$-algebras.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $R\left< x,y \right>$ the free $R$-algebra on indeterminates $x$ and $y$. If $z_i=xy^i$, I want to show that the $R$-subalgebra generated by the elements $z_i$ is itself a free $R$-algebra. However, I'm not really sure what it is I'm supposed to be showing. My professor told me that the easiest way to go about doing this is show the map
$$R\{x,xy,\cdots,xy^n\} \to R\{x,y\}, $$
is an injection. But I don't understand why this immediately gives us that $R\{x,xy,\cdots, xy^n\}$ is free. It seems to me like I must have misheard him. What he seems to be suggesting is that we may take any collection of monomials in $R\{x,y\}$, then they must generate a free $R$-algebra, since any inclusion map $R\{\cdot \} \to R\{x,y\}$ is going to be an injection, since only $0$ can map to $0$. If this were the case though, why would he not just ask us to prove this statement? Moreover, I can't find anything online to back this claim, so there's clearly something I'm not understanding.

Comment: Maybe it might help to think of it rather as a map $R \langle g_0, g_1, \ldots, g_n \rangle \to R \langle x, y \rangle$ defined such that $g_i \mapsto x y^i$?  Then the image of that map is exactly the subalgebra generated by $z_i$, and if you can show that map is injective, then the image is isomorphic to $R \langle g_0, g_1, \ldots, g_n \rangle$.

Comment: The notation $R \{ x, xy, \dots, xy^n \}$ is a little confusing; it is referring to the free $R$-algebra on $n+1$ indeterminates, but those indeterminates are given names $x, xy, \dots xy^n$ which are referring to their images under a specific map into $R \{ x, y \}$. And as Daniel Schepler says the question is to prove that this map is injective.

Comment: @DanielSchepler is there any way that the map wouldn't be injective? It seems like if we're mapping sets of indeterminates, the only way for an element to be mapped to 0 is if it were 0 in its pre-image.

Comment: @TyPerkins what you're trying to show is that there are no "hidden" algebraic (read: polynomial) relations between the $z_{i}$s in $R\langle x, y\rangle$. Consider the example instead given by the $R$-algebra morphism $R\langle g_{0}, g_{1} \rangle  \to R\langle x, y \rangle$ defined by $g_{0} \mapsto xy, g_{1} \mapsto xyxy$. Then $g_{0}^{2} - g_{1}$ is in the kernel of this map.

Comment: @AlexWertheim that clears things up. Thank you very much.